# Be DRY with Angular promises in services

Tags: angularjs, promise

What is the right way to use promises in services, when using a third party library that uses xhr and not $http ?

```
        getSomething: function(user, repo) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
        client.doSomething().promise().then(function(result) {
                $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                    deferred.resolve(result);
                });
            }, function(err) {  
                $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                    deferred.reject(err);
                });
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
```

Using the $rootScope like that seems ugly and not Angular-ish, but so would passing the scope as a parameter.
Is there any better way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be the perfect use for [$q.when()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q#when):

> Wraps an object that might be a value or a (3rd party) then-able promise into a $q promise. This is useful when you are dealing with an object that might or might not be a promise, or if the promise comes from a source that can't be trusted.

`$q.when()` returns a `$q` promise, so your code can be simplified to:

```
getSomething: function(user, repo) {
    return $q.when(client.doSomething().promise());
}
```

Comment: Hey Justin, thanks for coming by, actually I tried when and it doesn't apply to the scope :/